# Can we stop Vue from performing Client Side Hydration for a specific component?

Tags: vue.js, client-side-validation, hydration

I am fairly new to `Vue` and we are facing a problem where the total `DOM` size for our page has increased because we are storing a lot of data in `DOM` config for Vue client side hydration. For SEO purposes, we can't skip on server-side rendering.

I was hoping if there is any way by which we can block hydration from bailing on few of the `Vue` components?

So basically, can we force SSR to skip appending "data-server-rendered" attribute.

Comment: Did you a find a way to do it?